# How to deep-link to SoundCloud iOS App search without losing query?

Tags: ios, soundcloud, deep-linking

When I try to deep link to the Soundcloud iOS app using the following URL scheme:

`"https://soundcloud.com/search?q=\(query)"`

the app opens to the search screen, but the query parameters are lost. If you uninstall the Soundcloud iOS app, the search works properly on the web. Is there any way to deep link to search in the SoundCloud iOS app while keeping the query?

Answer (score 2):

SoundCloud is using Universal Links.  If you look at their [apple-app-site-association](https://soundcloud.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association) file, you will see that they do not support deep linking from the `/search` web endpoint:

```
{
  "webcredentials" : {
    "apps" : [
      "33KQ7TW725.com.soundcloud.TouchApp",
      "PBQEYM9L4Z.com.soundcloud.RAC.EnterpriseAlpha",
      "PBQEYM9L4Z.com.soundcloud.rac",
      "3XW8MM2T22.com.soundcloud.pulse.production",
      "3XW8MM2T22.com.soundcloud.pulse.debug",
      "PBQEYM9L4Z.com.soundcloud.pulse.alpha"
    ]
  },
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "3XW8MM2T22.com.soundcloud.pulse.production",
        "paths": [
          "/notifications",
          "/you/stats",
          "/you/stats/*",
          "/you/tracks"
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "33KQ7TW725.com.soundcloud.TouchApp",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /-",
          "NOT /-/*",
          "NOT /connect",
          "NOT /connect/*",
          "NOT /imprint",
          "NOT /jobs",
          "NOT /jobs/*",
          "NOT /login",
          "NOT /login/*",
          "NOT /mobile",
          "NOT /pages/*",
          "NOT /pro",
          "NOT /pro/*",
          "NOT /settings",
          "NOT /signin",
          "NOT /signin/*",
          "NOT /student",
          "NOT /student/*",
          "NOT /terms-of-use",
          "/you/collection",
          "/you/library",
          "/you/likes",
          "/you",
          "NOT /you/*",
          "/",
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This could of course change at any time, but based on SoundCloud mobile development history, unlikely to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really know why this question is getting downvoted, the Soundcloud devs link to here saying they take questions and offer support here on Stackoverflow, so I don't understand any potential negative reaction to this question. It seems like a bug in their app (or at least a bad user experience) that on iOS search links (sent in text messages or otherwise) will redirect to the app won't actually bring up the search properly. But I understand what you mean about their mobile development history. Wish I could just fix it myself.

Comment: It is a bad UX, but we have to work around the system that has been dealt to us.  Not sure why you're getting downvoted, have an upvote to offset some of the hate.